# Is prophet Mohammed's "Last Sermon" an accurate translation?

Tags: religion, quotes

[The poorly-cited Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Farewell_Sermon) states:

> The Farewell Sermon (Arabic: خطبة الوداع‎, Khuṭbatu l-Wadā), also
>   known as Muhammad's Final Sermon or The Last Sermon, was delivered by
>   Muhammad on the 9th of Dhu al-Hijjah, 10 AH (9 March 632) in the
>   Uranah valley of Mount Arafat.

[Whether Mohammed existed](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10966/what-is-the-historical-evidence-that-the-prophet-muhammad-existed) doesn't concern me, but [this page](http://www.islam-watch.org/authors/89-other-authors/134-fraudulent-translation-of-muhammad-last-sermon-egalitarian.html) states that his famed "Last Sermon" is a fake from 1991.

The top of 4.630.000 Google results for "[last sermon](https://www.google.nl/search?q=last+sermon)" are indeed unsourced.

As [my last Facebook comment quoting it](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3857469006279&set=a.1273801416204.2032216.1564999382&type=1) got [censored without comment](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3857468566268&set=a.1273801416204.2032216.1564999382&type=1), I'd like to know whether that part ("You will neither inflict nor suffer any inequity.") was representative of the religion of Islam.

Comment: Why not ask that questions at the [Islam SE](http://islam.stackexchange.com/?as=1)?

Comment: The question "is it part of Islam?" is not one that can be meaningfully answered here. Can we change this to "Is this an accurate translation?" Even then, Islam.SE is probably a better site.

Comment: @Chad I didn't know there was one, thanks. [I've asked it.](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/is-prophet-muhammads-last-sermon-an-accurate-translation)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was answered on IslamSE.

Comment: Hard to say, I don't think anyone who was there is still alive to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation is accurate and is often quoted in many books such as [this](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=9SZ3RQZ4vWwC&pg=PA167&lpg=PA167&dq=last%20sermon%20%22suffer%20any%20inequity%22&source=bl&ots=yrkTZfNIh2&sig=ZVgC6gITuWfFKCsktuDZ3tCbslg&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=last%20sermon%20%22suffer%20any%20inequity%22&f=false) and [this](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=QlozJ12_C-8C&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=last%20sermon%20%22suffer%20any%20inequity%22&source=bl&ots=D5sLX16wD_&sig=yDsiHnfl-tFp0BKEFSkg4_9YSKo&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=last%20sermon%20%22suffer%20any%20inequity%22&f=false). An example of the translated text in context:

> O People, just as you regard this month, this day, this city as Sacred, so regard the life and property of every Muslim as a sacred trust. Return the goods entrusted to you to their rightful owners. Hurt no one so that no one may hurt you. Remember that you will indeed meet your Lord, and that he will indeed reckon your deeds. Allah has forbidden you to take usury (interest), therefore all interest obligations shall henceforth be waived. Your capital is yours to keep. **You will neither inflict nor suffer any inequity.** Allah has judged that there shall be no interest and that all the interest due to Abbas ibn 'Abd'al Muttalib [the Prophet's uncle] be waived.
>
> Reference: [iupui.edu](http://www.iupui.edu/%7Emsaiupui/lastsermonofprophet.html?id=61)

Comment: Why is this post downvoted?

Comment: I guess because it belongs [there](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/3032/is-prophet-muhammads-last-sermon-an-accurate-translation) and [the answer there](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/3036/691) says not all of the popular English version can be found in the Arabic original.