# Is Muhammad (pbuh) mentioned only four times in the Quran and in three of those instances could be used as a title the praised one or chosen one?

Tags: religion, islam

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/36111/32459 says:

> **The name Muhammad actually appears in the Qur'an only four times, and in three of those instances it could be used as a title – the "praised one" or "chosen one"** – rather than as a proper name. Source: Did Muhammad Exist? (2012), p. 17

it is from http://www.americanthinker.com/articles/2012/04/inventing_muhammad.html

is it true?

Comment: Let's avoid self referential questions, they are not notable.

Comment: @Sklivvz The information is from American Thinker though. Doesn't that meet the notability requirement?

Comment: @called2voyage But isn't Sadiq's point that is isn't actually in the American Thinker article. He may be just asking if the article really says that.

Comment: @DavePhD Ok, I was mistaken, it doesn't actually come from American Thinker it comes from the book mentioned in that article *Did Muhammad Exist?*. That should also meet notability requirements.

Comment: @called2voyage not if Sadiq's question is merely whether American Thinker really said that.

Comment: @DavePhD Oh, I see what you're saying. I thought he was questioning the original claim, not whether that claim was actually in the source.

Comment: Occurences of Muhammad in the Quran are [trivial to search for.](http://search-the-quran.com/search/mohammed)

Comment: @DJClayworth "and in three of those instances could be used as a title the praised one or chosen one" is not trivial, however.

Comment: @Sadiq-Further explanation with reference for the above quote is added in the same answer. Read the material above this quote "That is all as far as Qur'anic mentions of Muhammad by name go. In the many other references to the messenger of Allah, this messenger is not named, and little is said about his specific actions. As a result, we can glean nothing from these passages about Muhammad's biography. Nor is it even certain, on the basis of the Qur'anic text alone, that these passages refer to Muhammad, or did so originally." and feel free to question it further!